# Create or update one to many relationship in Prisma

Tags: mysql, typescript, prisma

I'm trying to update a one to many relationship in Prisma. My schema looks like this

```
model A_User {
  id            Int          @id
  username      String
  age           Int
  bio           String       @db.VarChar(1000)
  createdOn     DateTime     @default(now())
  features      A_Features[]
}

model A_Features {
  id       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  description    String
  A_User   A_User? @relation(fields: [a_UserId], references: [id])
  a_UserId Int?
}
```

I'm trying to add a couple of new features to user with id: 1, or update them if they are already there.

I'm trying doing something like

```
const post = await prisma.a_User.update({
        where: { id: 1},
        data: { 
            features: {
                upsert: [
                    { description: 'first feature'},
                    { description: 'second feature'}
                ]
            }
        }
    })
```

The compiler isn't happy, it tells me

```
Type '{ features: { upsert: { description: string; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<A_UserUpdateInput, A_UserUncheckedUpdateInput> & A_UserUncheckedUpdateInput) | (Without<...> & A_UserUpdateInput)'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'features' does not exist in type '(Without<A_UserUpdateInput, A_UserUncheckedUpdateInput> & A_UserUncheckedUpdateInput) | (Without<...> & A_UserUpdateInput)'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1572, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: A_UserSelect; include?: A_UserInclude; data: (Without<A_UserUpdateInput, A_UserUncheckedUpdateInput> & A_UserUncheckedUpdateInput) | (Without<...> & A_UserUpdateInput); where: A_UserWhereUniqueInput; }'
(property) features: {
    upsert: {
        description: string;
    }[];
}
```

I can't work out how to do it nor I can find clear help in the documentation. Any idea on how to implement it or where I can find some examples?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "*update them if they are already there*". If they are already there in the ```features``` relation for that specific ```A_User``` or if they exist *anywhere* in the ```A_Features``` table?  

 

Also, If one of the features you're trying to add already exists, *how exactly* do you want that specific feature to be "updated"?

Comment: I'm quite new at this back end stuff, so apologies if it's unclear. What I think I need to do is to check if a feature with that specific description exists, if it doesn't I'll need to create it and add it to the user, if it does exists I'll just need to add it to the user. By "updating" I guess it would mean remove a feature and insert another one on its place. Already your comment made me understand that I've been looking at this in the wrong way. Thanks

Comment: Okay, that helps. Just one more clarification. Are you trying to "append" or "overwrite" the existing features. For example, let's say a ```User```  with ```id``` of 1 already has two ```features``` with the ```description``` "feature1" and "feature2" respectively. Now you run the update operation on the ```User```  with ```id``` of 1, providing ```features```:  "feature2" and "feature3". What will be the desired final state of ```features```  for the ```User``` with ```id``` of 1 after the update? Do keep in mind that "feature2" was already present before your update operation.

Comment: In the case above the final state will be "feature2" and "feature3" ("feature2" doesn't change while "feature1" is overriddent to "feature3").

Comment: Thanks, one more question so I can provide a specific solution. 

Can two different ```A_User``` records have ```A_Features``` records in their  ```features``` with the exact same ```description``` field?  To phrase it another way, is a ```A_Features``` record with a certain ```description```  unique to one ```A_User``` record or can be connected to many ```A_User``` records?

Comment: Yes, it can be connected to different users. It can be considered like an enum if you want.

Comment: I've written up a solution based on all the clarifications you have provided. I would suggest doing two things. First, please consider editing your question to make your requirements a bit more clear (so it can help people in the future who are having similar problems). Secondly, you should consider joining the [Prisma Slack](https://slack.prisma.io/)  community. We try our best to provide assistance to all our users over there!

Answer (score 13):

I'm providing my solution *based on the clarifications you provided in the comments*. First I would make the following changes to your Schema.

#### Changing the schema

```
model A_User {
  id        Int          @id
  username  String
  age       Int
  bio       String       @db.VarChar(1000)
  createdOn DateTime     @default(now())
  features  A_Features[]
}

model A_Features {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  description String   @unique
  users       A_User[]
}
```

Notably, the relationship between `A_User` and `A_Features` is now many-to-many. So a single `A_Features` record can be connected to many `A_User` records (as well as the opposite).

Additionally, `A_Features.description` is now unique, so it's possible to uniquely search for a certain feature using just it's description.

You can read the [Prisma Guide on Relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#many-to-many-relations) to learn more about many-to-many relations.

#### Writing the update query

Again, based on the clarification you provided in the comments, the update operation will do the following:

- **Overwrite** existing `features` in a `A_User` record. So any previous `features` will be disconnected and replaced with the newly provided ones. Note that the previous `features` will not be deleted from `A_Features` table, but they will simply be **disconnected** from the  `A_User.features` relation.
- **Create** the newly provided features that do not yet exist in the `A_Features` table, and **Connect** the provided features that already exist in the `A_Features` table.

You can perform this operation using two separate `update` queries. The first update will **Disconnect** all previously connected `features` for the provided `A_User`. The second query will **Connect or Create** the newly provided `features` in the `A_Features` table. Finally, you can use the [transactions API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide#transaction-api) to ensure that both operations happen in order and together. The transactions API will ensure that if there is an error in any one of the two updates, then both will fail and be rolled back by the database.

```js
//inside async function
const disconnectPreviouslyConnectedFeatures =  prisma.a_User.update({
    where: {id: 1},
    data: {
        features: {
            set: []  // disconnecting all previous features
        }
    }
})

const connectOrCreateNewFeatures =  prisma.a_User.update({
    where: {id: 1},
    data: {
        features: {
            // connect or create the new features
            connectOrCreate: [
                {
                    where: {
                        description: "'first feature'"
                    }, create: {
                        description: "'first feature'"
                    }
                },
                {
                    where: {
                        description: "second feature"
                    }, create: {
                        description: "second feature"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})

// transaction to ensure either BOTH operations happen or NONE of them happen.
await prisma.$transaction([disconnectPreviouslyConnectedFeatures, connectOrCreateNewFeatures ])
```

If you want a better idea of how `connect`, `disconnect` and `connectOrCreate` works, read the **Nested Writes** section of the [Prisma Relation queries article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes) in the docs.

Comment: This is amazing, you help me realise what was wrong with my approach, I'll go more in-depth with the documentation you linked. Thank you for the time you dedicated to this.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help!  

Please consider marking this as the correct solution if it solved your problem, so other people can reference it in the future.

Comment: Hi Tasin, do you think you could have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964434/one-to-many-relationships-with-self-on-prisma?

Comment: Hey, @Riccardo, really sorry for the late reply, I was a bit busy for the last few weeks due to personal reasons. Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Tasin, what are your thoughts on using `disconnect: []` in place of `set: []`? I still seem to wipe off other related records on the many side when I use `set: []`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by wipe off? Does `set: []` not have the desired behavior you're looking for?

Comment: @TasinIshmam since this is m-m dont we have to make a third model?

Comment: @Anoushk Prisma has the concept of an [implicit many to many](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations), so it's not necessary to create a new model (most of the time).

Comment: This is just a bad way of programming. What if you need to track the original connection date? Deleting existing relations and re-inserting the same relation is just wasted I/O in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The TypeScript definitions of `prisma.a_User.update` can tell you exactly what options it takes. That will tell you why the `'features' does not exist in type` error is occurring. I imagine the object you're passing to `data` takes a different set of options than you are specifying; if you can inspect the TypeScript types, Prisma will tell you exactly what options are available.

If you're trying to add new features, and update specific ones, you would need to specify how Prisma can find an old feature (if it exists) to update that one. Upsert won't work in the way that you're currently using it; you need to provide some kind of identifier to the upsert call in order to figure out if the feature you're adding already exists.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference/#upsert

You need at least `create` (what data to pass if the feature does NOT exist), `update` (what data to pass if the feature DOES exist), and `where` (how Prisma can find the feature that you want to update or create.)

You also need to call `upsert` multiple times; one for each feature you're looking to update or create. You can batch the calls together with `Promise.all` in that case.

```
const upsertFeature1Promise = prisma.a_User.update({
  data: {
    // upsert call goes here, with "create", "update", and "where"
  }
});
const upsertFeature2Promise = prisma.a_User.update({
  data: {
    // upsert call goes here, with "create", "update", and "where"
  }
});
const [results1, results2] = await Promise.all([
  upsertFeaturePromise1,
  upsertFeaturePromise2
]);
```